Flutter: Image_picker working on testflight and not app store
I have a flutter mobile app that uses image_picker package to access camera and photos.
I configure it in my info.plist like this:
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This lets you take pictures for product listing.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This lets you take pictures for product listing.</string>
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires speech recognition access to enable voice search functionality for a more convenient user experience.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This lets you select photos from your gallery and attach them to your listing.</string>

The problem is, when I install it from testflight everything works fine, but when I use app store version, for some users the photo settings don't even appear (right screenshot), and for others it appear with this message 'photo private access this app can show your photo library but can only access the items you select'(left screenshot).



In order to resolve this this is the steps I did:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build ios --release

Then I republished the app again to app store with XCode.
With this the error was solved. I hope my solution can help you.
